# Every two objects in a concrete category that have bases of the same cardinality are isomorphic.

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove a statement.

> Every two objects in a concrete category that have bases of the same
>   cardinality are isomorphic.

Its [Exercise 3 page 50 from Khelemsky, Lectures and exercies on Functional Analysis](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=wjzZCLzx6hUC&lpg=PA50&ots=2aAEg5N7Mx&dq=Every%20two%20objects%20in%20a%20concrete%20category%20that%20have%20bases%20of%20the%20same%20cardinality%20are%20isomorphic.&hl=ru&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q&f=false). Definition of Basis:

> Let $(K,\square)$ be a concrete category, and $X$ an object in $K$. A subset $S \subset \square X$ is called basis of this object if for every $Y \in K$ and for a mapping (i.e., a morphism in $Set$) $\phi : S \to \square Y$ there is  a unique morphism $f(\varphi) : X \to Y$ in $K$ such that $\varphi = (\square f(\varphi)) j $

Comment: What have you tried? There is only one possible proof and nothing comes into your way while writing it down, right? Also, it may help to prove it first for some concrete concrete categories ;), for example vector spaces.

Comment: For category of vector spaces is obviously because "categorical basis" of vector space it is just standart linear basis of it. Vector spaces isomorphic iff they basises have same cardinality - it is standart fact from linear algebra.

Comment: I get some relations between these morphisms. Let $q_x = (\square f(j_y \varphi)), q_y = (\square f(j_x \varphi^{-1}))$, $j_x, j_y$ - natural embeddings. Then:
$q_y j_y \varphi = q_x$, 
$q_y q_x j_x = j_x$, 
$j_y \varphi = q_x j_x$ 
dual relations, of course, also performed.

Comment: The argument for vector spaces works verbatim for concrete categories. Just replace "linear map" by "morphism", etc. Don't get confused.

Comment: But when I work with vector spaces I use next argument chain: categorical basis its linear basis $\to$ isomorphism in sense of linear algebra its the same that isomorphism in sense of category theory $\to$ two vector spaces isomorphic (by linear algebra definition) when their basises have same cardinality. So, I cant use second argument "isomorphism in sense of linear algebra its the same that isomorphism in sense of category theory" in general situation.

Comment: You will have to unfold the proofs from linear algebra.